# Max allowed inductive load (pump) for a given relay

Tags: relay

I am using [Omron G5RL-1A-E-HR](https://www.omron.com/ecb/products/pdf/en-g5rl.pdf) relay in my project with these specs:

[image: Relay specs]

I am using the high inrush type with max allowable current of 16 amps. I have used with water heaters up to 2 kW and air conditioners rated approx 2000 VA. Good thing about air conditioners is that they have a stabilizer which also delays the turn on of air conditioner. As such, there is no risk of high inrush current. However I am not sure if I turn it off when the air conditioner is running. Anyways, I haven't seen a failure in almost an year.

What's the max hp pump that I can put on this relay for a reliable operation? This case is different from air conditioner because motor will pull current as soon as I turn the relay ON. Do I need to make any changes to the circuit to improve it's life?

Answer (score 1):

For motors, you should be looking at relay ratings that specifically apply to motors. For NEMA ratings (USA) look for horsepower (Hp) ratings. For IEC ratings (worldwide) look for [**IEC Utilization categories.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utilization_categories)

For the  Omron G5RL-1A-E-HR relay, use the ratings highlighted below. LRA and FLA mean motor locked rotor and full load amps

[image]

Note that the number of test operations is 6,000 for the motor ratings vs. up to 50,000 for the other ratings. The number of test operations is probably a good indication of the expected life. For longer life, you might consider using a motor contactor. If the relay is switching a lower current than the maximum rated current listed, that should extend the life. Look at the Moron durability curves.